# PHP Arrays between 2 Functions

Tags: php, arrays, json, function

i used an exsiting code from a tutorial and need to change it.
The original code doesnt use an array, but i need it.

In my `index.php` i am calling the function with a tag:

```
else if ($tag == 'getinvbykost') {
        $kstalt = $_POST['kstalt'];
        $get = $db->GetInvByKost($kstalt);
        if ($get != false) {
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["ean"] = $get["ean"];
        $response["name"] = $get["name"];
        $response["betriebsdatenalt"] = $get["betriebsdatenalt"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "nicht erfolgreich";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

the function `GetInvByKost($kstalt);` is defined in `DB_Functions.php`.

the part is:

```
public function GetInvByKost($kstalt) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT ean, name, betriebsdatenalt FROM geraete WHERE kstalt='$kstalt' AND accepted='0'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        }
        return $result;
        //echo $result[1];
        }
        else {
            // user not found;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

the problem is, the function GetInvByKost returns an array.
the part in the index.php

```
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["ean"] = $get["ean"];
$response["name"] = $get["name"];
$response["betriebsdatenalt"] = $get["betriebsdatenalt"];
```

isnt made for an array, only for a single line.
how do i can get the values in the array to build my output?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` returns a **flat** array. This means you can't access returned array by a key. So `$get["ean"]` is wrong and `$get[1]` is correct. You can access result of `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` only by index, not key. You have `SELECT ean, name, betriebsdatenalt...` in your query, so index of "ean" is equal to 0,  "name" is equal to 1 and so on. Therefore, 3 parts of your code should be change in this way:

```
 `$get["ean"]` => ` $get[0]`
 `$get["name"]` => `$get[1]`
 `$get["betriebsdatenalt"]` => `$get[2]`
```

**Update:**
So, the index.php file should be like this:

```
else if ($tag == 'getinvbykost') {
    $response = array();
    $kstalt = $_POST['kstalt'];
    $get = $db->GetInvByKost($kstalt);
    if ($get != false) {
    // echo json with success = 1
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["ean"] = $get[0];
    $response["name"] = $get[1];
    $response["betriebsdatenalt"] = $get[2];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "nicht erfolgreich";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it is still no array in the index.php file or?